# Java mapping an object model to classes

Tags: java, serialization

Given some sort of document object model with methods like `int getInt(String col), getFloat, getString, getDate, etc.`, and classes wither either plain public fields, or public setters such as `setName(String), setAge(int), etc.` I want to map my document record to the specified Java type.

I have seen this done with various large JSON, SQL, etc. libraries, just by taking say `MyRecordObject.class` at run time, no compile time code gen using any sort of schema files.

But how is this implemented? Does Java have some sort of low-level interface for representing a DOM/record structure and mapping it to specific Java classes?

```
//to create something like this
Record record = readRecordFromMyGenericFileFormat();
TodoItem todo = record.as(TodoItem.class);
```

Comment: For some of these libraries you can look at [the source](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java). But it's most likely done through reflection. i.e. look at the key names of the json, and find corresponding fields in the passed class.

Comment: Instead of mapping DOM to objects, consider mapping the source of the DOM to objects, perhaps XML to objects.

Comment: I don't control the source unfortunately, its provided by some enterprise library with a lot of legacy (and about half dozen layers of transforms, network transfers, etc.). I could maybe transform it to JSON/XML then map that back, but that seems wasteful and I am unlikely to get that past code review even vs 100's of manual `todo.setDate(record.getDate("date"))`,

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to use reflection to dynamically set the values of fields in an instance of a Class.

[Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) might be useful and save you some trouble. [Example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.basic)

```
 Employee employee = ...;
 PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(employee, "firstName", firstNameValue);
 PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(employee, "lastName", lastNameValue);
```

You'd have to fetch the field name (`"firstName"`) and value (`firstNameValue`) from your generic file format.

If the field name information is not available in your file format, perhaps getting the fields dynamically via reflection could work for your use case.
There are multiple high quality tutorials on [Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html) online.

Comment: There is no higher level interface? I considered doing this from ground up reflection, but seems like a lot of complexity (field types, check have all required fields, check no unexpected fields, etc.) and would likely need a lot of performance tuning (looking up / mapping properties etc. per record per field for 10,000's of records for a single web server request)

Comment: There is no such higher level interface that I know of. Performance will always take a hit when using reflection. You have specific needs and will most likely need specific code.